Why is yarn producing this undefined error?
I am trying to upgrade eslint-config-airbnb so I run npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb
But I get the error:
install-peerdeps v3.0.3
It seems as if you are using Yarn. Would you like to use Yarn for the installation? (y/n) y
ERR undefined


Looks the same as this issue : https://github.com/nathanhleung/install-peerdeps/issues/228
Try deleting your package-lock.json.
